# Getting specific array from local json file in angular 5 via ngfor

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I've local json file having arrays. I want to get specific array in html document although i can get it in javascript using for loop but how to show this in html document.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.static_data.model.length; i++) {
  console.log(data.static_data.model[i]);
}
```

This works but problem is in HTML, it's not displaying.

```
<li *ngFor="let model of data; let i = index"> {{ model.static_data.model[i] }}</li>
```

It also don't show any error in console. Any help/hint will be appreciated. If there is better way to do this, Kindly share.

Comment: its not working because you need to create `observableOf` and subscribe to its changes

Comment: Thank Shashank, I'll try observables but i've basic understanding for it yet

Comment: Cool, if that approach doesn't work, share your code and put a comment with me as `@`

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly consume the JSON file using HttpClient and subscribe it and then push the contents into an array.**

### The AppModule

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### The AppComponent

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
export class AppComponent implements ngOnInit {

  public YourModel : any;

  ngOnInit() : void
  {
       this.getJSONFromLocal().subscribe(
          data => {
                    //Bind the data emitted by JSON file to model class here
                    this.YourModel = data;
                  },
          error => console.error(`Failed because: ${error}`));
  }

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public getJSONFromLocal(): Observable<any> {
         return this.httpClient.get("./someLocalFile.json")
                         .catch((error:any) => console.log(error));
     }
}
```

### Your HTML

```
<li *ngFor="let model of YourModel;">model.someProperty</li>
```

Comment: Thanks Kunal, really appreciate your effort, let me try this and will get back to you in moment.

Comment: if your'e using angular-cli, put the someLocalFile.json in "assets" folder and do this.httpClient.get("assets/someLocalFile.json")